# XLDeploy dar package version number

Tags: xl-deploy

When I created a dar package and send it to XLDeploy. The version of the dar package is generated as shown below. How I can put application version number instead of this random generated version number.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The XL Deploy manifest format has an option to specify the version in the `deployit-manifest.xml` file. See also `udm.DeploymentPackage` node: https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/concept/xl-deploy-manifest-format.html